# How to adjust picture when browser gets smaller?

Tags: html, css

I want the hand to always be showing when the width of browser decreases.

But when the width of browser decreases the hand no longer showing.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWdEVR

```
<header>
  <div class="image"></div>
</header>

html, body { 
     height: 100%; 
}

* { 
     margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}

header {
    height: 70%;
}
.image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/er5sypbyluenzco/Its%20ok.jpeg")no-repeat 0em -8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add "center" to your background property

```
.image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/er5sypbyluenzco/Its%20ok.jpeg")no-repeat center -8em;
}
```

Comment: nice that works, but what if I want the hand be on the right and not center?

Comment: You could add something like this background-position: right -500px center; and adjust the -500px accordingly to align it just right.  Kindly mark as solved if I helped you out :)

Comment: Here is another codepen . I want 123456789 to be showing everytime the width of browser gets smaller. But what happens is only the first few numbers show when the browser width gets to smallest point.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZdeQX

Comment: start a new question and I will answer right away for you, just tag css!